# If you have a topologically ordered graph, will a stable sort based on max-distance to a root preserve the topological order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, priority-queue, topological-sort

The partial order of a DAG should be compatible with the max-distance total order of any subgraph reachable from any given root, right? So does a stable sort preserve the topological order? Alternatively, is there a good algorithm that topologically sorts while also respecting any total order on a subgraph that is a function of max-distance to roots and is compatible with the topological order?

Edit: specified that the distance measure considered is the max-distance. Assuming that the number of roots is small and storing the max-distance to each root is fine.

Comment: Or your root is also the source node that you used for your topological sort, then yes, they are in fact the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The tree with vertices A, B, C, D and with edges A->B->C, A->D has a valid topological ordering A-B-C-D but dist(A, D)=1 and dist(A,C)=2. So no sort (stable or not) that sorts by distance preserves this ordering.

The tree with vertices A, B, C, D and with edges A->B A->C->D->B has no cycles (because the graph is directed). dist(A, B)=1, dist(A, D)=2 but D must appear before B in any topological ordering. So there is no topological ordering of this graph that is preserved by a sort by distance from A.

Comment: In the first example, the result of a sort is still topologically ordered. It is just a different topological order, which was allowed by the question (otherwise the only procedure that preserves the topological order would be the one that does nothing).

Second one is a good example that catches an ambiguity in the question text. Will edit question to specify max-distance, which is well defined for acyclic graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the alternatively question in the affirmative.

Given any two partial orders, we can construct a new partial order where `<` and `>` are defined by comparing the first, then breaking ties by the second.  Now do a topological sort with the new partial order and it is guaranteed to preserve all relationships from the first, and all relationships from the second that are compatible with the first.

If the two orders are compatible, it will respect all relationships in both orders.